# How do I add a subtree to an existing prefix in a new clone?

Tags: git, git-subtree

I have a main repository with two subtrees in the "external/" folder.

When I clone the repository, it downloads all the files, including the code that I previously pushed after the Git subtree command.

I want to clone that main repository on another machine and recreate the subtree structure, but the Git subtree add command fails because the folder where I want to put the subtree in already contains the folder and files.

```
> git clone https://URL/<main>
> git remote add <component> https://URL/<component>
> cd <main>
> git subtree add --prefix external/<component> <component> master
ERROR: prefix 'external/<component>' already exists.
```

How do I solve this or, is there a better way to have the subtree structure recreated for new clone operations?

Answer (score 2):

The point of Git subtree is that you don't need to "recreate" anything in another location or on another machine. When you `clone` the repository, it *already contains* the subtree as normal files via normal commits!

If you just want to "refresh" or "update" the contents of the subtree, try `pull`.

```
git subtree pull --prefix external/<component> <component> master
```

If for some reason (and could you please clarify) you really do want to start over, you need to remove the subdirectory and then re-add the subtree.

```
git rm -fr external/<component>
git commit -m "Removing old subtree"
git subtree add --prefix external/<component> <component> master
```

Answer (score 1):

I want to do exactly the same and totally understand why the existing two answers are not accepted, because the following question/problem is not solved:

> I want to clone that main repository on another machine and recreate the subtree structure, but the Git subtree add command fails because the folder where I want to put the subtree in already contains the folder and files.

Well, the answer/solution is simple. You don't --

The `git subtree add` needs to be done *only once* to the git repo, during the first/initial import, and never needs to be done again. The detailed reason/explanation is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69958555/).

So in the cloned new main repository, if you want to push to subtree, just

1. Redo the `git remote add` in the new repository that you've done in the old repo before, *only once* as the setup.
2. Then push to subtree just as what you've been doing in the old repo before

`git subtree push --prefix external/<component> <component> master`

Viola! The git subtree can now be updated from the new location/repository as well.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are receiving is because the `substree` already exists:

`ERROR: prefix 'external/<component>' already exists.`

This is because when cloning the main repo you also received the code from the `subtree`. **When adding a *Subtree* to a repo you are committing the code from the external branch/commit-hash into your source repo; you are committing the source to your repo, not linking to an external repo**. If/when you want to pull-in the code base to a newer commit from the source repo of the *Subtree* you can execute the command:

`git subtree pull --prefix external/<component> <component> <branch>`

That command will pull in `HEAD` from the  specified repo & branch and places the code over top of the existing code in the `/external/<comonent>` path.  After you execute this `subtree` command you will still need to do a `git commit` to update the code.

**Key note about Git**: a *Subtree* differs from a *Submodule* in that a *Submodule* creates a reference/shortcut/link in the source repo to another (external) repo. With a *Submodule* the developer cloning the repo must also have credentials/access to the submodule-repo in order to pull that linked code into the repo being cloned.  **A *Subtree* is an code commit to the root repo. So if you have access to the repo you are cloning, you don't need access to the external-repo referenced in the *Subtree*.**